# MsoAutomationSecurity is ambiguous in the namespace of Microsoft.Office.Core

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to use `Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoAutomationSecurity` in vb.net to set the security mode of an application when opening an excel file. But when I declare this variable on my code in vb.net:

`Dim secAutomation As New Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoAutomationSecurity`

it has a blue lining below ***Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoAutomationSecurity*** and on the Error window, this is listed:

`'MsoAutomationSecurity' is ambiguous in the namespace 'Microsoft.Office.Core'`

`Type 'Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoAutomationSecurity' is not defined.`

I hope anyone could help me fix this.

**EDITED:**

```
Imports OfficeCore = Microsoft.Office.Core
Imports excelApp = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel


Sub ExcelSecurity()
    Dim secAutomation As OfficeCore.MsoAutomationSecurity
    secAutomation = Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoAutomationSecurity.msoAutomationSecurityLow
End Sub
```

[image: Duplicate Enums]

thank you!

Comment: I don't use Office Automation much so I'm not sure that this will work but, from what I can recall, try adding `Imports OfficeCore = Microsoft.Office.Core" at the top of the code file and then use `OfficeCore.MsoAutomationSecurity` instead.

Comment: @jmcilhinney , I tried what you have commented. But still the same error and result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem with this question is that on one (1) solution there are 4 projects. The reference on the other projects has a duplicate Reference when adding the said Reference which is the *Microsoft Office 14.0 Object Library*. When I see the References on the other projects, the *Microsoft Office 14.0 Object Library* has a duplicate with different versions, to fix this problem I just removed the outdated version of the Reference.

Answer (score 0):

This error throws due to not add reference for MS Office which installed on your machine. Under project solution > References > Add references > COM > Microsoft office 16.06 Object library marked as checked and saved.

[image]

After showing your code minor modification needed as below:

```
    Imports OfficeCore = Microsoft.Office.Core
Imports excelApp = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel


Sub ExcelSecurity()
    Dim secAutomation As OfficeCore.MsoAutomationSecurity
    secAutomation = Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoAutomationSecurity.msoAutomationSecurityLow
End Sub
```

I hope it will resolve your issue without any other changes. Let me know if any further issues.

Comment: Still the same Sir, not defined and ambiguos.

Comment: Can you please share your code over here in question?

Comment: Why does the `OfficeCore` still exist if you will call the full name of the reference without using it?

Comment: Correct. I have updated the code. It is working fine for me.

Comment: Can I see you Object Browser Sir? My Object Browser look like that. I attached an Image that the Definition of `MsoAutomationSecurity` has a Duplicate.